# Django 1.3 autocompletion

Tags: python, django, class, autocomplete, view

I would like to know if there was a way to enable auto-completion for django class-based views.

I really like the new way to build views. It saves me a lot of time.
The thing is, i rewrite a lot the class methods :

- dispatch
- get_context_data
- get_queryset
- ...

I lose time redefining these methods with super, args ...

I'm working on Pydev/Eclipse. Is there a way to implement autocompletion for this or do i have to look for an other IDE.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There is a way extending classes. Check this [class for creating a view that dispatches based on request.method](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1071/) or [this](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/437/).

Isn't autocomplete or an IDE, but you can avoid a lot of "code typing".

Answer (score 0):

You can probably create a template for that in PyDev if it's always the same thing... See: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_compltemp.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PyCharm of JetBrains

http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/

for me and my coworkers is the best python IDE and have the best suport.

Best US$ 99 ever!